# Why use clipping instead of scan-converting all lines?

Tags: graphics, clipping

This is just a general, high-level question.

In computer graphics, why is it better to use clipping instead of scan-converting each line and then activating only those pixels that are within the viewport?

Answer (score 0):

Some reasons:

- **culling invisible (pieces of) primitives**: a primitive or a part of a primitive fully outside the viewport (or behind the near plane) will not have to be rasterized at all post-clipping.
- **rasterization performance**: with clipping, even for the pieces that are still visible, no additional visibility computation has to be done post-clipping per scanline (i.e. computing the scanline spans that are within the viewport / between the near/far planes).
- **accuracy**: rasterization is based on interpolation with incremental computations which are more difficult/expensive to make accurate if the range of allowed input coordinates is not restricted to the viewport.